# SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException caught but still displaying error log

Tags: java, android, exception

I am trying to open a database to test if the database exists. I wrote the code in a try and catch statement to catch the SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException if the database doesn't exist.

However, even if I catch the SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException, the error log is printed in the Logcat. Is that normal ? I haven't invoked the method printStackTrace on the exception. Is there a way to remove the exception log ?

Fortunately, the app still runs normaly even after the try and catch statement.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    myContext = this;

    try
    {
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        database.close();
        Log.v("Database Log", "Database exists !!");
    }
    catch(SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException e)
    {
        // The database doesn't exist; Lets create it

        Log.v("Database Log", "Database doesn't exists !!");
    }
```

Logcat

```
17:30:43.587: E/SQLiteLog(2054): (14) cannot open file at line 30191 of [00bb9c9ce4]
17:30:43.587: E/SQLiteLog(2054): (14) os_unix.c:30191: (2) open(/data/data/com.appsplus.hearthstonecollection/databases/hearthstonedata) - 
17:30:43.667: E/SQLiteDatabase(2054): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.appsplus.hearthstonecollection/databases/hearthstonedata'.
17:30:43.667: E/SQLiteDatabase(2054): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
```

Comment: The logcat doesn't show what you're logging in your `catch` block. That looks like the native code which is logging - in that case there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Actually, The Logcat shows my logging statement. I have just erased it from the question Logcat.

Comment: My point is you have no control over what the SQLite code is logging. You're catching the exception but you can't stop those error logs.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have answered my question.